# Is this the correct usage of the Factory pattern?

Tags: c#, factory-pattern

I've recently began to look at programming patterns, and I'm currently working on a way to create several closely-related concrete classes for some pages with certain properties from a website.

All I really would like to know is whether or not the pattern I am currently using is appropriate to the problem, whether or not there are any improvements that could be made, and whether or not there are better ways of tackling this probel other than the Factory pattern.

Thanks for your help!

```
    // Abstract factory
    public abstract class PageFactory
    {
        public abstract Page GetPage();
    }

    public abstract class Page
    {
        public abstract string Url { get; }
        public abstract PageItem[] Items { get; }
    }

    public abstract class PageItem
    {
        public abstract string XPath { get; }
        public abstract string POSTParameterName { get; }
    }

    // Concrete factory
    public class CreateAccountPageFactory : PageFactory
    {
        public override CreateAccountPageFactory GetPage()
        {
            return new CreateAccountPageFactory();
        }
    }

    public class CreateAccountPage : Page
    {
        public override string Url
        {
            get { return "http://www.x.com/join"; }
        }
        public override PageItem[] Items
        {
            get { return new CreateAccountPageItems().ToArray(); }
        }
    }

    public class CreateAccountPageItems : List<PageItem>
    {
        public class EmailAddressTextbox : PageItem
        {
            public override string XPath
            {
                get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            }
            public override string POSTParameterName
            {
                get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I don't understand what isn't appropriate about this question, could you explain what I might have messed up upon?

Comment: Sorry about that, the comments were added in at the wrong places. It was just to separate the concrete and abstract factory classes for readability

Comment: All right. So the answer is: yes, this is an example of an abstract factory pattern, and perhaps you should seek advice on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you very much - I asked on SO because I didn't know which site to post this on